# VBA: ComboBox populated by an Array

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have a form that I'm trying to populate the ComboBox with an Array that should be full of elements based on a loop. However when I'm attempting to initialize the form and populate the ComboBox I'm getting a `Subscript out of Range Error`

I'm not really sure why I'm running out of the range so I could use some help examining my code. I'm not the most familiar with VBA so I could really use a second set of eyes to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim refConcentrations As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, LRow As Long

    With Sheets(2)
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row + 1
    End With
    ReDim refConcentrations(1 To LRow) As Variant

    j = 1
    For i = 2 To LRow
        'Check if Current Session User is equal to any of the Stored ECNs
        If Sheets(2).Range("A" & i) = VBA.Environ("UserName") Then
            'If So, Store that ECN in Array
            refConcentrations(j) = Sheets(2).Range("E" & i).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    ReDim Preserve refConcentrations(1 To j - 1) ' <-- resize array to number of elements found
    ComboBox_PreviousECN.List = refConcentrations() ' <-- Set ComboBox Dropdown to equal the elements in the Array
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't remember if this is obligatory but try declaring in the first line `Dim refConcentrations()`.

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Remove the ```()``` from ```ComboBox_PreviousECN.List = refConcentrations()```

Comment: @BigBen I'm not sure.. when the error pops up it says ```Runtime Error 9: Subscript out of Range``` and only gives me options for ```OK``` and ```Help```  normally there is a ```Debug``` option when I get other errors but this the first time I haven't gotten one.

Comment: @Warcupine That fixed it thanks. Do you mind if I ask why that changed anything? I've seen arrays use and not use ```()```'s at the end so I'm curious as to what defines the situation in which they should be used like that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because it expects an index when using ```()``` where without that it's the entire array variable.

Comment: If users are sorted you can also use RowSource instead array (find first and last occurance on the sheet(2) and use indexes to build range)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `()` to the name of an array tells the compiler to look for an index.

> The notation used to refer to an element of an array consists of the variable name followed by parentheses containing an index number indicating the desired element.

The `Error 9: Subscript out of range` error is thrown because:

> You referenced a nonexistent array element.

that is, the `null` element called by `()`.

The VBA reference on the `List` property of the `ComboBox` element says:

> Use List to copy an entire two-dimensional array of values to a control.

Similarly:

```
a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
For Each x In a
Debug.Print x 'works
Next x
Debug.Print a 'throws an error
Debug.Print a() 'throws an error
Debug.Print a(0) 'returns 1
```

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/subscript-out-of-range-error-9
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.combobox.list